# Actualizar UI desde otro proceso c#

Tags: c#, delegados

Tengo un problema que no se como resolver.

La idea es la siguiente:
Tengo una clase que se encarga de las operaciones de lectura desde un puerto serie. Esta clase tiene un delegado y el evento creado que se dispara cuando llegan datos por el puerto.

Cuando llegan los datos el evento se dispara y de hecho la primera vez que abro y utilizo el formulario anda de diez y se actualiza un textbox con los datos recibidos.

Pero al cerrar y volver a abrir el formulario ya no funciona y me arroja " No se puede llamar a Invoke o a BeginInvoke en un control hasta que se haya creado el identificador de ventana."
Itente destruir el formulario, establecer todo a null, etc pero aun asi no me actualiza la segunda vez.

Clase Formulario donde esta el UI

```
public partial class RFIDConfigForm : Form
{
    SerialFuncs serialfunctions;
    StaticConfig funcs;
    public RFIDConfigForm(SerialFuncs serial)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialfunctions.eventMensaje += new delegateDataRecived(OnClienteEventMensaje);
        funcs = new StaticConfig();
    }

    //al recibir el evento intento actualizar textbox
    protected void OnClienteEventMensaje(string mensaje)
    {
        txtLectura.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                txtLectura.Text = mensaje.Substring(0, mensaje.Length - 1);
                actualizar(mensaje);
            }));
    }
}
```

//Clase de donde disparo el evento cuando recibo datos por el serial

```
public delegate void delegateDataRecived(string mensaje);
public class SerialFuncs
{
    int asistencia =0;
    public event delegateDataRecived eventMensaje;
    System.IO.Ports.SerialPort vloPuertoSerial;
    string msg = "";

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //evento que se dispara cuando llegan datos al puerto serial
        try
        {
            if (vloPuertoSerial != null)
            {
                if (vloPuertoSerial.IsOpen)
                {
                    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
                    msg += indata;
                    //Si esta esta en 1 es xq se carga nuevo, esta configurando lector o se modifica existente.
                    if (msg.IndexOf('@') != -1)
                    {
                        if (this.asistencia == 1)
                        {

                            eventMensaje(msg);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Marca asistencia");
                        }
                        msg = "";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Alguna idea del por que se ejecuta una vez bien y al cerrar el formulario y abrirlo ya lanza el error?

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Probaste desuscribir el delegado cuando cerras el formulario?

Answer (score -3):

Al final decidí ocultarlo y mostrarlo sin cerrar el form ya q si no produce el error.

Comment: No es una respuesta a la pregunta, tampoco una solución al problema. Convendría poner eso en comentarios y no en una respuesta